# Is the movement of the cursor on the screen a result of graphical transformation?

Tags: user-interface, operating-system, graphical-interaction

I am occupying myself with image processing right now, to be specific, with geometrical transformation and I was wondering, if the movement of the mouse cursor on the screen, is a result of geometrical transformation which is being calculated by the operating system. If it is, then I guess that behind every movement of a graphical object on a screen there is a system which calculates the geometrical transformation. Is that right? And does someone maybe know what keywords to search for, to obtain more information about graphical transformation on e.g. computers, smartphones? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely system specific. On some systems, mouse cursor movement is done in hardware. On other systems, it is done by drawing operations triggered either by interrupt or poling.

Comment: @user334403 do you maybe know where these geometrical transformations are used (besides image processing softwares)?

Comment: What transformations are you intersted in? If you're drawing in software, you can make a backing store of the screen before drawing the cursor. Then you can use the backing store when you move the cursor away. You can do bitwise transforms that do not require a backing store.

Comment: I am interested in the basic transformations like translation, scaling and rotation. Do you know where they are used mostly?

Comment: Cursors don't generally scale or rotate. Translation is done by redrawing.

Comment: ok, so the translation of a cursor in not done as a form of image processing? Do you maybe know where geometrical transformation is used then in the technical area?